# How can I add a clear input button to forms in Bootstrap & CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a live search dropdown list from bootstrap-select and I need to add an 'x' icon whenever someone types in something into the search bar to clear it.

Here is the example I'm using: https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search_1

Currently you have to delete whatever you wrote manually.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a JavaScript solution.
Many roads to this path...

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap select picker I think you are looking for this one:

change the selector as per your code.

```
$('.btn-group.bootstrap-select.open input').val('');
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```